# Did Qui-Gon Jinn's Force Ghost communicate to Obi-Wan Kenobi post-RotS?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Did Qui-Gon Jinn's Force Ghost communicate to Obi-Wan Kenobi post-RotS?

> Yoda-"An old friend has learned the path to immortality. One who has returned from the netherworld of the force, your old master."
>   Obi-Wan Kenobi-"Qui-gon?"
>   Yoda-"How to commune with him, I will teach you."

We have indirect evidence (Obi-Wan learned how to become the Force Ghost himself, by ANH), but he could have learned it himself, or simply from what Yoda told him.

**Is there any *direct evidence* in G-, T- or C- canon that Qui-Gon Jinn's Foce Ghost communicated to Obi-Wan Kenobi post-RotS?** (the way we see Obi-Wan communicating to Luke)

Comment: Related question restricted to [tag:the-force-awakens]: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/114112/769

Answer (score 7):

This is addressed in Canon by Episode VI of *Obi-Wan Kenobi*:

> Obi-Wan had apparently been unable to contact Qui-Gon's spirit for about ten years after *Revenge of the Sith*. Following the events of *Obi-Wan Kenobi*, he becomes able to see Qui-Gon, who says that he "was always here. You just were not ready to see."
>
>  [image: Screenshot of Obi-Wan Kenobi showing Qui-Gon's Force ghost]

Later, according to [*Master and Apprentice*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Master_and_Apprentice_(short_story)), a short story from *From a Certain Point of View*, Qui-Gon appears to Obi-Wan during the events of *A New Hope*.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I am aware, the closest you'll get is in Legends, in the [Epilogue](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Lord:_The_Rise_of_Darth_Vader#Epilogue) of the novel Dark Lord: The Rise of Darth Vader, he directly speaks to Obi-Wan:

> The epilogue depicts Obi-Wan Kenobi, now under the guise of Ben Kenobi living as a hermit on Tatooine to watch over the infant Luke Skywalker from a distance. Kenobi is shocked at the news to hear that Darth Vader, whom he believed he killed in his duel against him on Mustafar, is alive. He is then contacted by the spirit of his late Master, Qui-Gon Jinn, who assures him that Luke will grow to confront his father when the time is right and that Vader will never step foot on Tatooine ever again, for fear of his memories coming back to haunt him.

Comment: Note that as per April 2014, this novel is no longer considered to have any canon status other than as a "legend"; http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/the-new-star-wars-canon-guide/

Comment: Ah okay good point, I had missed that, thanks

Comment: However, they have implied that some pre-Ep VI EU works may be later added back in, and all EU works are available for inclusion in the new canon, so this is still a good answer with that clarifier you have added (e.g. still answer questions with LucasCanon answers, just with the appropriate marker)

Answer (score 3):

From the Disney canon novel, [*From A Certain Point of View*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/From_a_Certain_Point_of_View), Qui-Gon visits his former padawan, Obi-Wan Kenobi as a force ghost after Luke and Kenobi discover the stormtroopers' slaughter of the Jawas in *Episode IV: A New Hope.* This short story was called *Master and Apprentice* and was written by Claudia Gray.

Answer (score -1):

Qui-Gon Jinn appeared to Obi-Wan on Mortis during Star Wars: The Clone Wars Season Three Mortis trilogy. At the time he probably chalked it up to the power of Mortis affecting his mind, but when Yoda revelaed it, it all made sense to him.

Comment: The OP asked for post Revenge of the Sith (RotS). The Clone Wars took place before.