# Where is Qui-Gon Jinn?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Besides Yoda and Obi-Wan Kenobi, Qui-Gon Jinn is also supposed to have become a Force-Ghost (even more, he probably taught becoming one to the other two, according to the end of RotS). So, did Qui-Gon's ghost appear anywhere in TFA?

Comment: Related to, but more restricted than: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24204/769

Comment: http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Liam-Neeson-Wants-Return-Star-Wars-Here-How-It-Can-Happen-69084.html

Comment: Did I miss the other force ghosts showing up? I don't remember that at all.

Comment: Qui-Gon did not teach Yoda how to become a Force Ghost. Towards the end of the Clone Wars TV series, Qui-Gon's spirit led Yoda to the [Force Priestesses](http://www.starwars.com/databank/force-priestesses), who then taught Yoda. Yoda taught Obi-Wan how to communicate with Qui-Gon (that part is explicitly stated at the end of RotS), who then lead Obi-Wan to the Priestesses.

Comment: @DCShannon Sorry for the confusion, no, Yoda and Obi-Wan merely were heard in [Rey's visions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111978/769) (see also [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112324/769) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/113166/769)), but no Force-Ghosts at all so far. But these two already had their appearance in RotJ, Qui-Gon would have been a bigger surprise...

Comment: @RemyLebeau When did that happen? Oh I see, I haven't watched [Season 6 (The Lost Missions)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_episodes#Season_6:_The_Lost_Missions_.282014.29) yet...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. He's not in it. Not even in a flashback.

As to *why* he wasn't in the film, you'd have to ask Jar Jar Abrams but my personal guess it that his character simply wasn't a big enough part of the Prequel trilogy to merit inclusion into a film that was heavily focused on being a  retro pastiche of the *Original* trilogy

Comment: Don't let him see you say that, he's not the [biggest fan](http://heroicuniverse.com/j-j-abrams-gives-the-star-wars-prequels-the-cold-shoulder/) of the prequels!

Comment: You mean a static character that served nearly no meaningful plot device other than dying didn't make a flashback? that's good :)

Comment: @enderland I kind of liked Qui-Gon, but that might be because he wasn't Jar Jar :P