# Why was this character able to appear as a force ghost?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi-2022

In the final episode of the kenobi television series we see

> Qui-Gon Jinn appear before kenobi as a force ghost.

However, if I remember correctly in the Clone Wars television series it was established that

> Qui-Gon did not complete his training, and so could only appear to the living voice-only. In fact Yoda had a lot of trouble trying to listen to him, and could only properly communicate with him once he landed on a planet that was strong with the force (midi-chlorians?). Yoda then completed the trials that would allow him to properly manifest as a force ghost postmortem.

Did I miss something between these events?

Comment: Because retcons

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24204/did-qui-gon-jinns-force-ghost-communicate-to-obi-wan-kenobi-post-rots

Comment: For what it's worth, the idea that appearing as a Force Ghost was a "standard" ability of the Jedi and something one needed to pass trials to "unlock" were both foreign ideas to the canon until that one Clone Wars episode. Star Wars has its merits but consistency isn't one of them.

Comment: Always in motion, the canon is.

Comment: To be fair, nowhere did it say the relevant character couldn't keep on learning how to manifest himself. After all, it doesn't say where the Skywalkers learned how, so either Anakin had a lot of learning to do in the 25-ish years he spent as Vader or he got one heck of a crash course after he died at Endor.

Comment: <waves hand around> This is not the canon you are looking for

Comment: What SpaceWolf says.  The Kenobi series is a full decade after the fall of the Jedi, there's plenty of time for his manifestation skills to have improved.  So what's the problem?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy the problem is that now Qui-Gon not appearing in the OT makes no sense in-universe (yes, the character didn't even exist in 1977, and Yoda was Obi Wan's master not him, but still).

Comment: Yoda also heard Qui-Gon while meditating in the Jedi Temple in Attack of the Clones

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the short story *Master and Apprentice* from 2017's *From a Certain Point of View*, Jinn continued training from beyond the grave until he was able to visually materialize.

> Even after death, we continue to learn. - Qui-Gon Jinn

It is stated that it took him nearly ten years, lining up with the time period of *Obi-Wan Kenobi*.

It makes sense that he was able to continue his journey as a ghost, as characters like Anakin seem to have learned everything after they died.

Comment: Wow this is cool. TBH I never expected an answer other than "retcon".

Comment: @Setsu Given how long an Obi-Wan project has been in development, I wonder if the story element was based on the script, or if the show element was based on the story.